# flash cs4: how to convert symbol to flex component?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-cs4, flex-skins

I've read on the net that there is the flex component kit for flash that allows me to convert flash symbol to flex component or container.

I tried installing Flex_Skins_12_05.mxp that suppose to enable these features in flash cs4 but under the commands tab i can't see any commands related to flex conversion.

can someone please forward me to the appropriate plugin to install in flash cs4 in order to convert it's symbols to be usable with flex ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to also download the flash component kit from  http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex_skins

after installing this package, when i execute adobe flash, under commands i can convert a symbol to a flex component or container.